# How to store Json object in sharedpreferences flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart, sharedpreferences

**Here it is the post method of login API, When user will logged in the json object will automatically stored in shared Preferences**
I dont know how to store object in shared preferences

```
void login(String email, password) async {
try {
  Response response = await post(Uri.parse('https://app.getjustdone.com/api/login'),
      body: {
    'email': email,
    'password': password,
  });
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var data = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
    // print(data['user_info']);
    pageRoute(data['token']);
    setState(() {
      isApiCallProcess = false;
    });
    showToast(context, data['message']);
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()),
    );
  } else {
    var data = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
    showToast(context, data['message']);
  }
} catch (e) {
  setState(() {
    isApiCallProcess = false;
  });
  showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text("Server Error"),
          actions: [
            FlatButton(
              child: Text("Try Again"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            )
          ],
        );
      });
}
```

}

```
void pageRoute(String token) async {
SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await pref.setString("user", token);
```

}

**Here is the **json response** I want to store in shared preferences**

```
{
"status": true,
"message": "Log In Successful.",
"token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiIxIiwianRpIjoiMjIyMWI3MmU2N2U1YjBlZTgyMmY0YWI0OWNlM2ExZTg0OWI4ZDljMjMwYzZhN2YzOWQxNDVlZTQ2MTliOWM5MTY5ODQ5Mjk0YjYwNzUwMTAiLCJpYXQiOjE2NDk0ODQ1MzQuOTI3OTY3LCJuYmYiOjE2NDk0ODQ1MzQuOTI3OTcsImV4cCI6MTY4MTAyMDUzNC45MTkwNzQsInN1YiI6IjMiLCJzY29wZXMiOltdfQ.lc5Avuw28uVoOX6DMAin8Q09Gy-xbyg7GAOGWwjCIn_IpQxiM6KkLe9dzKxCVyyS8By9IJKbIYFpvFYAbN1XlHzZrGAKMkfAmtkMpll6p0RacvIQnPDLM3NhJzWSXRc5vbYKdeLQSjNqhCO08M2K83IVhRgYFL_6p77kRwndusltOXWQVzlIMGAITpNP2J32j2rISR1Zh9qrlDdEYcyt3jZcekD6BUZG_SxxH0PviApi4YwKEkmzEK2-JfW1qqppNWObL_Nfu4A4nIIN9XoAclwdKJ9CPAkT5-YY0YvjZea-eLkBpEiHb8SuxqwAHU4afxOif2zhAgjYrkq2C4MW67L8MfDuzB21TtM9iKygC5RCEuAuuPv5IGnJtouL287qmx_bKhgq-wu7rDGlHJm2obAChyMN81TRztrETRTpFeXG7vBu5raVk2zv2Ady5bST3Lzj3v_jqsZPyjWyc-2qMHYHc-3y18_psgytUZYtLvQAXvug6CvF9kOs96oUrcJAW7zit6lA4KzSsMa-LzcpMnB7ny2nAxKvIajpaPag-JCawN6Ll1A5rSeHCb3AD5Z-9vhV_AkYEicpiBLGuDf6MNDlfPLdZPDVoQ1d58GK8tR2vvZzJrFtIVafGRPq-SEbFus0N9h9fUtxXAAS36hMNO_NNbe1ucWLdIQnl5pizoE",
"user_info": {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "munna",
    "role": "Master",
    "email": "munna@gmail.com",
    "phone": "01903932723",
    "image": "https://app.getjustdone.com/img/avatar.png",
    "balance": "0.00"
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharedPreferences accepts strings as type of data to store. So you should just encode and decode the data.

How to save the JSON:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.setString("user", jsonEncode(token));
```

and how to get the JSON:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
var myData = prefs.getString('user');
String token = jsonDecode(myData!); //Null check on the data you just got
```

Comment: Thank you. but here how can I access the objects (user_info) value like id,role,name

Comment: when I will get the json on other page I need the token and role which is inside another object so can you please tell me how to access those variables

Comment: You should be able to access it by `token["status"]` or `token["user_info"]["id"]` as a dictionary. But my suggestion is to create a class that has all that information and use a `fromJson` to access those parameters. Like: `MyClass.fromJson(jsonDecode(myData!))`. If you have some difficulty creating a class consider using https://quicktype.io/

Comment: void getCred() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var user = prefs.getString('user');
    String info = UserModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(user)).toString();
  }

  Future<TasktypeModel> getTaskApi() async {
    final response = await http.get(
        Uri.parse(NetworkConstants.BASE_URL + 'get-task-type'),
        headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer $info"});// I need to pass token here
    var data = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
  }

Comment: Brother I have created a the class named UserModel now I need to pass the token from the response I have stored in shared preferences and pass it as a authorization bearer token

Answer (score 0):

Shared preferences stores int, double, bool, String and List.

In this case you need to convert your json to string using `json.encode(myjs)`

If you want to access the object, you decode it using `json.decode(mystring)`